# Substring from character to character in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

How can I get sub-string from one specific character to another one?

For example if I have this format:

```
string someString = "1.7,2015-05-21T09:18:58;";
```

And I only want to get this part: `2015-05-21T09:18:58`

How can I use Substring from `,` character to `;` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be better:

```
string input = "1.7,2015-05-21T09:18:58;";
string output = input.Split(',', ';')[1];
```

Using `SubString`:

```
public string FindStringInBetween(string Text, string FirstString, string LastString)
{
    string STR = Text;
    string STRFirst = FirstString;
    string STRLast = LastString;
    string FinalString;

    int Pos1 = STR.IndexOf(FirstString) + FirstString.Length;
    int Pos2 = STR.IndexOf(LastString);

    FinalString = STR.Substring(Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1);
    return FinalString;
}
```

Try:

```
string input = "1.7,2015-05-21T09:18:58;";
string output = FindStringInBetween(input, ",", ";");
```

Demo: <kbd>[`DotNet Fiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jIXF1J)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

If you string has *always* one `,` and one `;` (and `;` after your `,`), you can use combination of [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
string someString = "1.7,2015-05-21T09:18:58;";
int index1 = someString.IndexOf(',');
int index2 = someString.IndexOf(';');

someString = someString.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1);
Console.WriteLine(someString); // 2015-05-21T09:18:58
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ne5KgI)</kbd>.

Comment: `int index2 = someString.IndexOf(';', index1 + 1);` will be more precise; and the string doesn't have to have exactly one `';'`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sure, that can be as another option.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex,

```
@"(?<=,).*?(?=;)"
```

This would extract all the chars next to `,` symbol upto the first semicolon.

Comment: How is this better than the other answers? How do you use it? As it is, this answer isn't very useful and could probably use some elaboration.