# C# Get text before and after character

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> Yes this post looks a lot like many other posts

It is not. Here is why:
I have a string:`:vixing!vixing@vixing.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #lirik :A Message`
I need to get the username. I need to get everything after position 0 and stop right before the **FIRST** `!`

How can I do this?

(Lang: C#, Program: Visual Studio 2015 Community)

Comment: There's no `0` in your string ... Or did you mean the position?

Comment: @Glorfindel Position. My bad. Should be more clear. Edited Post

Comment: In any case, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367051/substring-from-character-to-character-in-c-sharp) which is basically similar to yours.

Comment: String.substring(0, string.firstindexof("!"))

Comment: Or string.split('!')[0]

Comment: *Yes this post looks a lot like many other posts* You mean it lacks any evidence that you tried to solve your issue yourself?

Comment: Another option: `string userName = msg.Split("!".ToCharArray()).First().TrimStart(":".ToCharArray());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var text = ":vixing!vixing@vixing.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #lirik :A Message";
var pos = text.IndexOf('!');
var subText = text.Substring(1, pos - 1);
```

Text to print/display: `subText`

Comment: The OP says everything after position 0,  so it should be `Substring(1, pos - 1);`

Comment: @juharr, good call. Thank you.  Fixed.

Comment: @Roman: You will need `pos - 1` in the `Substring` now too.

Comment: Worked Perfect. I have to wait 6 minutes to accept it. lol. Thanks

Comment: Probably should also use `IndexOf('!', 1);` as well to skip looking at the first position, but wouldn't make a difference for the OP's example.  And a check if `pos` is negative (meaning that `!` was not found).